# How to get a nested array to a collection in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I have a response from an api, that returns something like so :

```
array:162 [▼
"WAN" => array:4 [▼
"available" => "1153.65000000"
"onOrder" => "0.00000000"
"btcValue" => "1.05385928"
"btcTotal" => "1.05385928"
 ]
"ONT" => array:4 [▼
"available" => "961.95000000"
"onOrder" => "0.00000000"
"btcValue" => "0.83237534"
"btcTotal" => "0.83237534"
]
"NCASH" => array:4 [▼
"available" => "114194.00000000"
"onOrder" => "0.00000000"
"btcValue" => "0.59495074"
"btcTotal" => "0.59495074"
]
....
```

Which is all good and dandy, however i would much prefer to work with collection methods.

I have tried to convert to a collection with the collect() method as so .

```
$collection = collect($returned, true);
```

However i am still not able to traverse the data like so :

```
$collection->WAN->available
```

Instead i get the following in my $results :

```
Collection {#408 ▼
#items: array:162 [▼
"WAN" => array:4 [▼
  "available" => "1153.65000000"
  "onOrder" => "0.00000000"
  "btcValue" => "1.05085979"
  "btcTotal" => "1.05085979"
]
"ONT" => array:4 [▼
  "available" => "961.95000000"
  "onOrder" => "0.00000000"
  "btcValue" => "0.83170197"
  "btcTotal" => "0.83170197"
]
"NCASH" => array:4 [▼
  "available" => "114194.00000000"
  "onOrder" => "0.00000000"
  "btcValue" => "0.59951850"
  "btcTotal" => "0.59951850"
]
....
```

So after plenty of mooching about i found this :

```
$results = json_encode($returned);
$results = json_decode($results);

$collection = collect($results, true);
```

This turns out to be a step in the right direction, yet i am still not able to traverse the data in a full collection style.

I now have the following returned to me :

```
 Collection {#572 ▼
 #items: array:162 [▼
 "WAN" => {#409 ▼
  +"available": "1153.65000000"
  +"onOrder": "0.00000000"
  +"btcValue": "1.05270563"
  +"btcTotal": "1.05270563"
 }
 "ONT" => {#411 ▼
  +"available": "961.95000000"
  +"onOrder": "0.00000000"
  +"btcValue": "0.81842706"
  +"btcTotal": "0.81842706"
 }
 "NCASH" => {#412 ▼
  +"available": "114194.00000000"
  +"onOrder": "0.00000000"
  +"btcValue": "0.60294432"
  +"btcTotal": "0.60294432"
 }
```

Which i can traverse like so :

```
$collection['WAN']->available
```

How can i make it like :

```
$collection->WAN->available
```

I have now ran out of ideas, and i cannot seem to find anything that might address this problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it have to be a Laravel Collection? I don't think you can do `$collection->property`, however, you can convert it to a `StdClass` completely if you want to have that.

Answer (score 0):

A `Collection` is simply a wrapper around an array. Your `collect` calls are returning the correct collection representations, but you are mixing object and array syntax. Doing something like `$collection->WAN` is not trying to get the value of "WAN" in an array named "collection", but is trying to get the value of an attribute in an object called "collection". `Collection` should be based off an array so `$collection->WAN` shouldn't work.

Your attempt with JSON functions work because when you decode JSON using `json_decode()`, it by default decodes it to an object, and you would decode it to an associative array by using a second optional parameter like `json_decode($json, true)`.

If you simply want to work with "collection methods", which I assume is something like `$collection->sum('available')` or similar, then either of your two approaches would work, although the first one would probably be faster. You just need to make sure you don't mix array notation (`$collection["WAN"]`) with object notation (`$collection->WAN`).

Comment: Thankyou for your explanation, i am quite new to this hence my lack of understanding. So you are basically saying that i cannot achieve what i thought was possible, and need to delve into this a bit more to understand the fundamentals? :)

Comment: @madmatuk You can use Laravel collection methods with the array you have, you just don't use `->` because it is object notation and you do not have an object. An object is not as easily traversable as an array, so you should use arrays (`[]` syntax). You do probably need to understand the fundamentals a bit more.